# Acronyms and new glossary are not shown in \printglossary

Tags: memoir, glossaries

I am using the following example in order to set up a memoir-file. The example is taken from: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=9423.

While this seems to work for the people in the thread my .glo-file does only contain entries from definitions stemming from these commands.

```
\newglossaryentry{culdesac}{name=cul-de-sac,description={passage
or street closed at one end},plural=culs-de-sac}
```

Symbols and acronyms are not part of my Glossary-file somehow. How would it be possible to fix that?

Moreover, is it possible to create a glossary without using the glossaries-package?

I am using texMaker on a Mac OS X-system. Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{memoir}


\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newglossary[slg]{symbols}{sym}{sbl}{List of Symbols}

\makeglossaries

% The following definitions will go in the main glossary

\newglossaryentry{culdesac}{name=cul-de-sac,description={passage
or street closed at one end},plural=culs-de-sac}

\newglossaryentry{elite}{name={\'e}lite,description={select
group or class},sort=elite}

\newglossaryentry{elitism}{name={\'e}litism,description={advocacy
of dominance by an \gls{elite}},sort=elitism}

\newglossaryentry{attache}{name=attach\'e,
description={person with special diplomatic responsibilities}}

% The following definitions will go in the list of acronyms

\newacronym{led}{LED}{light-emitting diode}

\newacronym{eeprom}{EEPROM}{electrically erasable programmable
read-only memory}

% The following definitions will go in the list of symbols

\newglossaryentry{ohm}{type=symbols,name=ohm,
symbol={\ensuremath{\Omega}},
description=unit of electrical resistance}

\newglossaryentry{angstrom}{type=symbols,name={\aa}ngstr\"om,
symbol={\AA},sort=angstrom,
description={non-SI unit of length}}

\begin{document}

\glsaddall

\printglossary 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you run `\makeindex` or `\makeglossaries`, as described in the manual?

Comment: erh, that would be the `makeindex` or `makeglossaries` without the ``\`` ;-)

Comment: I used the upper example and changed the make index command to this one: "/usr/texbin/makeglossaries" %.glo. Then ran pdflatex, make index, 2xpdflatex. It then displays all "normal" glossary entries but no acronyms or symbols.

Comment: @daleif: Of course ... I was too much into TeX commands instead of external programs

Answer (score 3):

In order to get the glossaries into the document, this setup requires the external tool `makeglossaries` and for the acronyms the `\printacronyms` command:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{memoir}


\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newglossary[slg]{symbols}{sym}{sbl}{List of Symbols}

\makeglossaries

% The following definitions will go in the main glossary

\newglossaryentry{culdesac}{name=cul-de-sac,description={passage
or street closed at one end},plural=culs-de-sac}

\newglossaryentry{elite}{name={\'e}lite,description={select
group or class},sort=elite}

\newglossaryentry{elitism}{name={\'e}litism,description={advocacy
of dominance by an \gls{elite}},sort=elitism}

\newglossaryentry{attache}{name=attach\'e,
description={person with special diplomatic responsibilities}}

% The following definitions will go in the list of acronyms

\newacronym{led}{LED}{light-emitting diode}

\newacronym{eeprom}{EEPROM}{electrically erasable programmable
read-only memory}

% The following definitions will go in the list of symbols

\newglossaryentry{ohm}{type=symbols,name=ohm,
symbol={\ensuremath{\Omega}},
description=unit of electrical resistance}

\newglossaryentry{angstrom}{type=symbols,name={\aa}ngstr\"om,
symbol={\AA},sort=angstrom,
description={non-SI unit of length}}

\begin{document}

\glsaddall

\printacronyms
\printglossary 

\end{document}
```

Compile as usual

- pdflatex foo.tex
- makeglossaries foo
- pdflatex foo

[image]

I omitted the screen shot for the glossaries, for the OP was already able to create the glossaries inside the document.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately I get the following error with your MWE --> ! Undefined control sequence. \printacronyms <--. I am still pretty new to Latex and the usage of glossaries so it could be a fault that I am making. But I can't think of the error source.

Comment: Okay... The error is gone, due to a distribution update. Nonetheless the acronyms are not shown... It is not in the .glo-file as well.

Comment: @BenR: Well, I can't say anything about that. I know, that for my TL 2014 (updated on 4th of August 2014) distribution this output generated. I will check again..

Comment: Could be something wrong with my general or path properties? Which information could be useful to determine this?

Comment: It seems to work with \makenoidxglossaries and \printnoidxglossaries.

Comment: @BenR If you use the `acronym` package option, the acronyms will be in the `acn` file not the `glo` file. When you run `makeglossaries`, make sure you don't include the file extension if you have multiple glossaries.